# how to draw vertical line in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a UIScrollView and I want to draw a vertical line that has a height of the UIScrollView contentHeight. How do I do this easily and without sacrificing performance? I am thinking of using a UIVIew with a very-very large height (because we don't know what the contentHeight of the scrollView will be) and adding it as a subview of the UIScrollView. Is there a better approach than this?

The line is basically 10px width, gray color, that spans from the top to the bottom of the scrollView.

Here's what I have as of now, I am basically overriding the UIScrollView drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (shouldDrawVerticalLineForProfile){
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGColorRef separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:47.0/255.0 green:47.0/255.0 
                                                     blue:47.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;

        // Add at bottom
        CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(30, 0);
        CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(30, 10000);

        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapSquare);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, separatorColor);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startPoint.x + 0.5, startPoint.y + 0.5);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, endPoint.x + 0.5, endPoint.y + 0.5);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);     
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Ummm, the easiest way would be too just add a UIView and set the background color.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   UIView *verticalBar = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
   [verticalBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
   [verticalBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,10,[scrollView contentSize].height)];

   [[self view] addSubview:verticalBar];
}
```

You don't need a "very very large height" because you know the maximum height via the scrollView.

Comment: This would have a lot more overhead than just drawing the line tho as ur instancing a lot of un-needed stuff.

Comment: That would be why this is the "easiest". :P

Comment: I agree with j_mcnally.. I would think that Core Graphics would be more optimized?

Comment: oh and by the way UIScrollView does not have a viewDidLoad.. are you saying do this inside the UIViewController that has a UIScrollView? If that's the case then that's not what I want. I need this to be in the UIScrollView

Comment: @j_mcnally Actually this is much faster than a way that overrides drawRect and uses CoreGraphics. It all has to do with how the CoreAnimation layer system works.

Comment: @xonegirlz, just put it in your UIScrollView and change the `scrollView` and `[self view]` to `self`.

Comment: i have no benchmarks on this i guess i always thought CoreGraphics was better and lighter weight.

Comment: @j_mcnally For doing the initial drawing this is true, but the CoreAnimation system does not know what a drawRect routine is going to draw and hence has to call it repeatedly. A UIView that has nothing but a background color is something the animation system knows exactly how it behaves and it only needs to rendered once and can be composited on the graphics hardware. (That's why the comments  generated by Xcode warn to be careful overriding drawRect when animation is involved).

Comment: @xonegirlz, yes, what I posted is for a UIViewController. If you dont have access to one with your scroll view, then all you need to do is add it to your `init` method instead of a view controllers `viewDidLoad`. As Justin Paulson said, just change `[self view]` to `self`.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:.6].CGColor);
  CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1);

  CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
  CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0, CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - 2);
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - 2);
  CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
  CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2);
  CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor colorWithRed: .34 green:.35 blue:.352 alpha:.6].CGColor);

  CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
  CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0, CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
  CGContextStrokePath(ctx);




}
```

add this to your UIScrollView's controller

the code i gave u draws a horizontal line but u should be able to adapt it.

Comment: do I need to call [super drawRect]? also what if I have a BOOL inside my UIScrolLView that determines whether this line should be drawn or not? Will this work? Can I just put an if statement in drawRect? I am just not sure when drawRect will be called

Comment: drawRect is called when the view is drawn in my experience i did not need to call super i have it exactly as i pasted it, sorry i didnt have time to modify it for you but it should be simple. You can wrap all that code an if statement that checks your BOOL. I use the code to draw a custom inset separator between table cells.