# How to draw the separator in UIScrollerView?

Tags: ios

I have a custom UIScrollerView . In the content of it, I add 5 UIButton horizontally. For each button , I want to add the separator on (Top,Right)
I have a idea. Just set `button.layer.borderWidth=1.f;` However, in the vertical layer of the right will overlap on the left layer of the next button. That is ugly :) .. Another idea is add two UIView on the top the right ..related to [how to draw vertical line in UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318502/how-to-draw-vertical-line-in-uiscrollview).. Is there any way better than it.. If I have 100 button , I have to add 200 UIView .. Is it too much ? If the overhead is considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 100 buttons, then I think you should prefer UICollectionView rather than scrollview.
You will get default separators and many more other features without any overhead.